# SendGrid mailer with Azure Function V2

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, sendgrid

I had been going through below piece of code for SendGrid mailer in Azure functions,

```
[FunctionName("SendEmail")]
public static async void Run(
[ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] Message 
email,
[SendGrid(ApiKey = "CustomSendGridKeyAppSettingName")] 
IAsyncCollector<SendGridMessage> messageCollector)
{
var emailObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutgoingEmail> 
 (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(email.Body));

var message = new SendGridMessage();
message.AddTo(emailObject.To);
message.AddContent("text/html", emailObject.Body);
 message.SetFrom(new EmailAddress(emailObject.From));
 message.SetSubject(emailObject.Subject);

 await messageCollector.AddAsync(message);
}

public class OutgoingEmail
{
public string To { get; set; }
public string From { get; set; }
public string Subject { get; set; }
public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

If my understanding is correct this will send a message to the message queue "myqueue" but I am confused that do I need to write a custom listener to the queue "myqueue" to get the message from queue and write a logic to call "client.SendEmailAsync" to send the mail or SendGrid bindng have some magic behind to automatically pickup the message and trigger mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is not quite correct.

This will LISTEN for a message on the queue.

And then call the SendGrid API to send the message passed in. This function expects a JSON serialsed message as input from the queue:

```
[ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] Message email
```

Comment: But if you see the example code it has an output binding so I assume this function sends message to queue. Please find the msdn link where I copied code from,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid#asynchronous-c-example

Comment: The queue is IN, the SendGrid is out.  Look for the line "Here's the binding data in the function.json file:" in the article.   {
          "type": "queueTrigger",
          "name": "mymsg",
          "queueName": "myqueue",
          "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
          "direction": "in"
        },

Comment: If the queue is "IN" then where would be "client.SendEmailAsync". Also if that is the case I need to write logic to send a message to the queue then only this azure function can pick up the message. As you can see that piece of code is just building up the mail message so where do I write the logic to send mail. If I am correct I need another listener which listens to the message in queue and process the message.

Comment: The send is abstracted away by the functions binding.  await messageCollector.AddAsync(message); effectively does the send. This code is purely a Microsoft example, you can use any trigger you like, or a timer to check a database for a message to send. It is up to you to decide how to get the message to be sent.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more doubt (as a beginner in azure function). How do I call this azure function? As this is ServiceBusTrigger triggered azure function I assume I have to send a message to the mentioned queue which has all the properties of type "OutgoingEmail". Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, for this example, you need to write to the queue. You can use any of number of bindings - see Supported Bindings at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings for other options.